# PHP/MySQL - Display DateTime as Date

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date, time

I'm a little knew to SQL & PHP and have been given the task of displaying some information from the database. I know how to query my database and display the info into tables on screen using PHP and so forth; however this time I've been given a slightly different challenge.

I have information stored in the DateTime format in the SQL database and whilst retrieving it I need to strip the time and display only the date. I've had a read through many of the date/time functions for SQL but for some reason this seems to be going almost straight over my head. I've had a browse of a few sites including the two links below, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to do such things within PHP etc. If someone could steer me in the right direction that would be excellent!

2 somewhat related threads I've browsed:
http://www.gfxvoid.com/forums/showthread.php?28576-PHP-Time-Date-Display
http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2006/02/17/1458.aspx

Logically, am I supposed to query the DateTime and then use PHP to reformat it the way I wish to display it? Or am I supposed to format the datetime using an SQL query?

Thanks very much!

Comment: In SQL query, use DATE(colum) to strip off time.

Comment: Do you need date somehow formated, or just the date part of datetime? if you only need date part DATE(yourdatetimecolumn) in sql query should be enough

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks guys. I only require the stripped Date at this point in time, but since I'm here. Is there a simple way to format the date to more standard format for example "2nd of March, 2012"? I believe I would need to use the strtotime() function or something similar?

Comment: By the way, just implemented your suggested method. Worked perfectly! Cheers :)

Comment: Updated my answer for your time format you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the DATE function around the date time.

SQL Column: created_at

```
2012-05-09 13:46:25
```

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE(created_at), '%D %M %Y') FROM Table`

Returns:

`9th May 2012`

**EDIT** as per comment:

To use it in PHP, you can do something like the following:

Query: (Notice the AS clean_date)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE(created_at), '%D %M %Y') AS clean_date FROM Table
```

then in in php:

```
<?php
echo "<tr><td>{$row['clean_date']}</td>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks tehlulz! Works great. When I'm displaying information that's been formatted like this, normally I would use:

echo "<tr><td>{$row['EventDate']}</td> for example (that's without formatting).

How would I call the $row so that it will display the data formatted?

Comment: Modified answer in response to your comment.

Comment: Wow, you are my hero! Thanks a lot, saved me a lot of reading I'm sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you check this in PHP when Display the date from Mysql

```
date('Y/m/d', strtotime($datetodisplay));
```

Sometime when you fetch the date from mysql, we have change that to time by using strtotime() funciton